# How to setup reverse proxy with nginx in windows server 2019 using docker?

Tags: windows, docker, nginx, hyper-v, nginx-reverse-proxy

Searched all web and there are many solutions for Linux but can not find any solutions for Windows.

**What I have**

Host; windows server 2019 + hyper-v + docker
 Containers one with nodejs(ui.domain.com) and other with php api (api.domain.com)

**What I need**

A nginx reverse proxy that could map both sub domains on port 80 into each container

Please don’t ask why I am using windows and not Linux, there are other application that work only in windows containers.

I am looking for a set of command lines which could accomplish this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can perfectly fine use Windows nothing wrong with that, however I would not use Nginx on windows they say this on their own website:

*Due to this and some other known issues version of nginx for Windows is considered to be a beta version.*

So you could technically work around it by running nginx also in Docker but I would say you are complicating things then. Since you have Windows Server 2019 I would just use IIS and reverse proxy into the docker containers this is much simpler and works perfectly fine.

You can do this by installing the following two applications into IIS:
URL Rewrite:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
Application Request Routing:
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

I basically do the same for my Kibana installation you can have a look on my tutorial and skip to the IIS part, and do the exact same but then for your docker containers:
https://ulyaoth.com/tutorials/how-to-install-elastic-stack-6-6-on-windows-server-2019/

There probably more specific guides on this, I did a quick google and found the following:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/IIS-Support-Blog/Setup-IIS-with-URL-Rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222
https://www.sapho.com/documentation/how-to-configure-microsoft-iis-http-server-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-sapho-server-running-on-apache-tomcat/
https://tecadmin.net/set-up-reverse-proxy-using-iis/

I hope that helps you! :)